# Increasing \footheight with scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I am experiencing a very strange issue. I am using scrlayer-scrpage to generate headers and footers. For headers, everything works great, but for footers, on every next page the footer height is getting larger (see example). What could be the reason for this?..

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ifoot[\the\footheight\quad\rule{2px}{\footheight}]{\the\footheight\quad\rule{2px}{\footheight}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{test}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\footheight` is total height of the foot, including height (space above the baseline) *and* depth (space below the baseline) of the foot.

Your rule starts on the baseline. So the height of the foot must be at least the height of your rule plus the depth of a `\strutbox`. Therefore `scrlayer-scrpage` enlarges the former `\footheight` by `\dp\strutbox`. On the next page your rule starts again on the baseline and so `scrlayer-scrpage` enlarges the`\footheight` from the last page by `\dp\strutbox` again ...

You can shift the rule down by `\dp\strutbox`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ifoot*{\the\footheight\quad\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{2px}{\footheight}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you have to shorten the rule `\dp\strutbox`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ifoot*{\the\footheight\quad\rule{2px}{\dimexpr\footheight-\dp\strutbox\relax}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can hide the height of the rule using `\smash`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ifoot*{\the\footheight\quad\smash{\rule{2px}{\footheight}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Note that

```
\ifoot*{\the\footheight\quad\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{2px}{\footheight}}
```

is a short version of

```
\ifoot
  [{\the\footheight\quad\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{2px}{\footheight}}]
   {\the\footheight\quad\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{2px}{\footheight}}
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sence, I was not aware of this behaviour. Now, I solved the problem by just defining the height of logos (which I'm actually using insteas the rule) by 'em', which is OK. But now, I'm facing following issue: on the 'first' page, I have large logo in the header, so it is increased for all the rest of the document, and vice versa in the footer I'm using on all the other pages a bit larger footer. Is there a possibility to separately define approproate header and footer height for the 'first' and the following pages, so scrlayer-scrpage does not complain and everything fits?

Comment: Please ask a new question with a new minimal working example. There you can use `example-image` instead your logos.  Is the first page a title page? And if your oiriginal problem here is solved, you could accept the answer.